# Untraceable malicious browser calls

Tags: browser, http, trojan, fiddler

I installed Fiddler 4 Beta to do some HTTP tracing.
I found a lot of calls being made to sites like : facebook, collegehumor and a bunch of other sites I've never visited.
Could not trace what/who is initiating these calls as I do not see any Windows Processes.
No one else is connected to my network.

I use both Google Chrome and IE10 on a Windows 7 box.

Please help me tracing and removing these malicious HTTP calls.

Comment: If your computer is doing something that you didn't initiate, it is quite probable that you have a virus. Run 2 or more anti-virus scans.

Answer (score 0):

[CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) is able to show you the process that has opened a connection. Identify the process responsible for the connections with this.

Answer (score 0):

When you visit a page, many connections are generated to other sites for tracking and advertising and not all of them are necessarily malicious.

Since you are using Fiddler, I assume the connections you see are from the browser process(es).

In fiddler itself, you should be able to see the request body and what type of data are they sending, and also the responses to these queries. You can also see what kind of process is initiating the connection if it's not the browser.

Try a tracking filter like Ghostery in Chrome to minimize these type of connections (and have more browsing privacy).